# Share react native not appearing in the bottom of the screen

Tags: react-native

The first picture is the buttons of the share exactly like the tutorial on its page.

The second picture is what happen when i click share ui component.

How could i do to show the shareButtons on the bottom.
I tried position absolute and bottom 0 but it disappears the buttons.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on the container, try `flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-end'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this library https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet
I could not make it work using the UI of the react share plugin.So i use this method of the plugin inside de action sheet:

```
   setTimeout(() => {                           
        Share.shareSingle(Object.assign({},shareOptions, {
             "social": "facebook"
        })).catch(err => console.log(err));
   },300)
```